# NullPointerException getting BluetoothManager in an Android Service

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

My `Discovery` class extends `Service` class. When I try to get its singletone from other class this way:

```
Discovery discovery = Discovery.getInstance();
```

I get a NullPointerException. This is the Discovery code:

```
public static Discovery getInstance(){
    if (discovery == null){
        discovery = new Discovery();
        discovery.initDiscovery ();
   }

   Log.i(TAG, "get discovery instance");
   return discovery;  
}

public Discovery() {
}

private void initDiscovery(){
    mDiscoveredDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) discovery.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);<--NullPointerException
....
}
```

Comment: Did you declared the bluetooth permission in the manifest file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not Android my friend.

To create a service you need to declare it in manifest:

```
  <service
        android:name=".DiscoveryService" />
```

After which you can instantiate it but **never using operator new**. Instead you need to call:

```
startService(context, new Intent(context, DiscoveryService.class);
```

There are other ways of firing a service intent but this will suffice for now.

The service's construction code should be placed at onCreate:

```
class DiscoveryService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        service construction code here
    }    
}
```

And its request handling code in onStartCommand:

```
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       handle incoming intent
   }
```

Now, if you do need to access a service instance probably the simplest way
of achieving it would be to declare and maintain a static instance reference within
the service. Do it like this:

```
class DiscoveryService extends Service {

    private static DiscoveryService inst; // <-----------------

    public DiscoveryService getInstance() {
        return inst;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        service construction code here
        inst = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        cleanup code here
        inst = null;
    }
}
```

This approach has its shortcomings, but unlike yours, it will work. Still use with care.

Finally - years of writing & reviewing Android code have led me to the conclusion 
that what most novice developers want when they ask for [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), is in fact an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)..
Please read the docs and make sure you got your class right.

Good luck.